Проблема видеоадаптера VirtualBox после установки Arch linux
После установки Arch Linux на VirtualBox, разрешение экрана - 1280x800.
grub не видит дисплей виртуальной машины. При вводе videoinfo, последняя строка - 'Adapter VGA Video driver': No info available. При этом выше, в адаптере VESA BIOS Extension Video Driver есть много режимов экрана, но нет 1920x1080 (полный экран) и установка какого-либо режима, экран размер не меняет.
Также экран не видит xorg (Can't open display) и Wayland (конкретнее Hyprland).
Драйвера для виртуальной машины установлены. Tакже установлен драйвер под Intel.

После установки минимального Arch Linux на VirtualBox - минимально это вот ( https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/arch-boxes/-/packages ) а не с иксами и вялеными гипергладами. То что вы хотите для этого нужно внимательно почитать данную статью на арчвики VirtualBox/Install Arch Linux as a guest и при этом постараться не cпутать host и guest

Прошёлся по статье, всё заработало. Спасибо!
